# Is it possible to produce two session with one accout using spring session

Tags: spring-session

I am using `Spring-session-jdbc`.

The demands are:

- One account shared in PC web and rest API for APP.
- When account login in PC web, the session max age is 30 mins.
- When account login in APP, the session max age is 60 mins.
- The session in PC web and APP does not have influence on each other.

I have not any idea about it .

Would you please give me some advice?

`Thank you very much`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

- dynamic set maxInactiveInterval in `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` implementation codes
- using Spring-session multiple session that PC web do normal requests and APP rest API requests with `_s=1` parameter , the APP rest API's jsessionid should be like 'SESSION:"1 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"'